# Prisma createCart function not able to return userId on query field

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, prisma

I am trying to create a cart and link it to a product and to a users ID but for some reason, I get this error when I try to query the userId field

"Cannot return null for non-nullable type (line 4, column 5):\n userId"

My datamodel.primsa

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
}

type Cart {
  id: ID! @id
  userId: ID! @id
  items: [Product!]! @relation(link: INLINE)
}

type Product {
  id: ID! @id
  productName: String!
  productDescription: String!
  price: Int
  images: [Image!] @relation(link: INLINE)
  sku: String
  category: Category @relation(link: INLINE)
}
```

My Mutation

```
mutation {
  createCart(data: {
    userId: "5dafd11da7b11b00087627d1"
    items: {
      connect: {
        id: "5dafcb9ba7b11b00087627c4"
      }
    }
  }) {
    id
    userId
    items {
      productName
    }
  }
}
```

[Tree View of the Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwYXE.png)

[Picture of Mutation and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K3nz.png)

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with `facebook-graph-api`?

Comment: Are you calling this mutation on Prisma endpoint or application endpoint? If application endpoint, can you please share resolver code?